# Comparison of dates not retrieving actual data in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to filter out data before date '31-01-2020' and after '01-01-2020' but the below query is not working. Am I missing something for comparison of dates?

```
select * 
from per_all_assignments_m paam
where 1 = 1
  and TO_CHAR(paam.effective_start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') <= '31-01-2020' 
  and TO_CHAR(paam.effective_END_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') >= '01-01-2020'
  and assignment_number like '%555%'
  and assignment_type = 'E'
```

Comment: Do NOT convert dates to strings for comparison.  The built-in date functionality is quite sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't turn the dates to string for comparison. First, the format you are using makes the comparison just wrong. And even you were using a proper date format, this would still be very inefficient.

Instead, compare them agains literal dates:

```
where 
    effective_start_date >= date '2020-01-01'
    and effective_start_date < date '2020-02-01'
```

Comment: the date column is in different format hence I want them both to be in the same format

Comment: @Sree: you are confusing the display format of the dates and their actual, internal representation. The format you are seeing is just a display format, that can be altered though database or session setting. But you actually have a column of `date`  datatype, so you need to compare it against another `date` value (which is what the above query does).

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
select * from per_all_assignments_m paam
where 1=1
and (paam.effective_start_date <= to_date('31-01-2020', 'dd-mm-rrrr') OR paam.effective_END_date >= to_date('01-01-2020', 'dd-mm-rrrr'))
and assignment_number like '%555%'
and assignment_type = 'E'
```